# Have a error with Scanner

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("Thats cool, I have thought that was a very interesting activity, how   many hours a week do you do that.");
String oftenHangOut = input.nextLine();
```

The next line has problems and I have no idea how to fix it.

```
int oftenHangOut = integer.parseInt(oftenHangOut);
if (oftenHangOut > 10){
    System.out.println("Wow thats a lot you must love to do that.");
}
else{
    System.out.println("Cool, you must love to do that.");
}
```

Comment: For a start, you could explain what it supposed to do and what it does instead.

Comment: integer isn't a class name, but Integer is

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a Scanner object anywhere ;) But, I think, you want to do something like that:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Thats cool, I have thought that was a very interesting activity, how   many hours a week do you do that.");
    String oftenHangOut = sc.nextLine();
    int parsedInt = Integer.parseInt(oftenHangOut);
    if (parsedInt > 10) {
        System.out.println("Wow thats a lot you must love to do that.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cool, you must love to do that.");
    }
```

or without parsing:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Thats cool, I have thought that was a very interesting activity, how   many hours a week do you do that.");
    int oftenHangOut = sc.nextInt();

    if (oftenHangOut > 10) {
        System.out.println("Wow thats a lot you must love to do that.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cool, you must love to do that.");
    }
```

Good technique is to use try-catch block. You will see what goes wrong, and why your appliaction stopped.

Answer (score 0):

```
int oftenHangOut = Integer.parseInt(oftenHangOut);
```

and to read an int you should do this

```
int oftenHangOut = input.nextInt();
```